# How to set one string to reference another

Tags: c#, string, reference

I want to set a `string s1` to refer to another `string s2`. I don't mean passing `s2` into a method with ref. *I want simply want `s1` to be the same as `s2` in **value and reference**.* So, [Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) would return true.

How do I do this? And is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Go look up string interning.

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to achieve. Obviously `s1=s2` achieves reference equality, but it does not sound like it is what you are looking for. Also please make sure to demonstrate "not so good" way you have already and explain in which way you want code to be better.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just thought that string was a struct and String was an object. My bad.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm working with a string from a TextBox object. Casting it to String won't cause any problems, right?

Comment: @DonovanKeating search engine you are using seem to be sub-optimal at best... Try google or bing - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%+string+vs+String... Or if search engines are not available checking documentation is a good starting point too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string - "Although string is a reference type..."

Comment: Agree with @AlexeiLevenkov, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. If you want to save memory, my answer can help. If you try to do anything else, you may be on the wrong track.

Comment: I'm trying to create filler text for the TexBox such as "Type Here". I want to see if the "Type Here" has the same reference with my string so I can know whether the user intentionally inputs "Type Here". This way, I do not treat the user string as filler text.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Examples:

```
if (s1 == s2) s1 = s2; // If you need to verify their values are equal first.

s1 = s2; // If you don't need to verify first.
```

PS: You say "want s1 to be the same as s2", so that's the opposite of the above then.

You can also use the String.Intern method, but that would have the effect that your string shares data with any other string in the intern pool which happens to be the same. In both cases you save memory.

Comment: Actually, I just found out that Object.ReferenceEquals returns the same values for ==. I'm still searching for a way to compare references.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: You can use Object.ReferenceEquals, or (object)s1 == (object)s2.

Comment: Try setting s1 = "a" and s2 = "a"
Use Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2) and it returns true

Comment: Yes it does return true, because s1 and s2 do share data in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's not what `Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)` does.

this example is from MSDN:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String s1 = "String1";
      String s2 = "String1";
      Console.WriteLine("s1 = s2: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
      Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s1, 
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s1)) ? "No" : "Yes");

      String suffix = "A";
      String s3 = "String" + suffix;
      String s4 = "String" + suffix;
      Console.WriteLine("s3 = s4: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s3, s4));
      Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s3, 
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s3)) ? "No" : "Yes");
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       s1 = s2: True
//       String1 interned: Yes
//       s3 = s4: False
//       StringA interned: No
```

s1 and s2 are different instances but `Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)` returns true. that means in this case it matches the value.

Comment: Not sure how comment about behavior of ReferenceEquals answers the question... Some clarification may help (along with explanation of what exact question you are trying to answer).

Comment: sorry i am not sure if he wants to use string or String. in the first case i am out of track.

Comment: I don't think I can use String because I'm actually working with a TextBox object and retrieving TextBox.Text, which is a string.

Comment: String and string is the same thing.

Comment: "The Intern method uses the intern pool to search for a string equal to the value of str. If such a string exists, its reference in the intern pool is returned."
Isn't this essentially the same as comparing by value?
@RomeoRomeo